# Error when preg_replace image src in content

Tags: php

```
<?php
$content = 'Image 1 <img src="//placehold.it/100x100" /> and image 2 is <img src="//placehold.it/150x150" />';
preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i',$content, $imgTags);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($imgTags[0]); $i++) {
    preg_match('/src="([^"]+)/i', $imgTags[0][$i], $imgage);
    $imag_src = str_ireplace( 'src="', '',  $imgage[0]);
    $image_url = "$i".$imag_src;
    $content = preg_replace("#(<img[^>]*>)#s", '<img src="'.$image_url.'" />', $content);
}
echo $content;
?>
```

Result can't replace exact position image src

```
Image 1 <img src="1//placehold.it/150x150"> and image 2 is <img src="1//placehold.it/150x150">
```

How to fix it to follow this result:

```
Image 1 <img src="1//placehold.it/150x150"> and image 2 is <img src="2//placehold.it/150x150">
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Currently since you do `preg_replace` on `$content` in a loop, the last iteration always overwrite the previous results as the pattern always match.

Comment: Did you mean to change the filename for Image 1 from `100x100` to `150x150`?

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to do is add the image number to the start of the `src` link, you can do that with:

```
$content = 'Image 1 <img src="//placehold.it/100x100" /> and image 2 is <img src="//placehold.it/150x150" />';
echo preg_replace('/(Image\s+(\d+).*?<img src=")/i', '$1$2', $content);
```

Output:

```
Image 1 <img src="1//placehold.it/100x100" /> and image 2 is <img src="2//placehold.it/150x150" />
```

If you also wanted to change image 1 to 150x150, you can use this:

```
echo preg_replace('/(Image\s+(\d+).*?<img src=")(.*?)\d+x\d+/i', '$1$2${3}150x150', $content);
```

Output:

```
Image 1 <img src="1//placehold.it/150x150" /> and image 2 is <img src="2//placehold.it/150x150" />
```